# How to fix the size of recorded video ? Like whatsapp trim video in fixed size?

Tags: java, android, video, camera, trim

I have recorded video and i want to trim video for specific size before saving it. 
i cant do it with specif time but  i want to to that with fixed data size. Like whatsapp  before saving it i want to  trim the video to fixed data size.

```
 mVideoTrimmer = ((K4LVideoTrimmer) findViewById(R.id.timeLine));
    if (mVideoTrimmer != null) {
        mVideoTrimmer.setMaxDuration(10);
     // mVideoTrimmer.setMaxSize(4);
        mVideoTrimmer.setOnTrimVideoListener(this);
        mVideoTrimmer.setOnK4LVideoListener(this);
        //mVideoTrimmer.setDestinationPath("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CameraCustom/");
        mVideoTrimmer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        mVideoTrimmer.setVideoInformationVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

And The method for the setting it to the time interval....

```
   public void setMaxDuration(int maxDuration) {
    mMaxDuration = maxDuration * 1000;
}

public void setMaxSize(int maxSize){

    mOriginSizeFile=maxSize*1024;

}
```

and The calculation For the trimming for specific time interval

```
 private void setSeekBarPosition() {

    if (mDuration >= mMaxDuration) {
        mStartPosition = mDuration / 2 - mMaxDuration / 2;
        mEndPosition = mDuration / 2 + mMaxDuration / 2;

        mRangeSeekBarView.setThumbValue(0, (mStartPosition * 100) / mDuration);
        mRangeSeekBarView.setThumbValue(1, (mEndPosition * 100) / mDuration);

    }


    else {
        mStartPosition = 0;
        mEndPosition = mDuration;
    }


    setProgressBarPosition(mStartPosition);
    mVideoView.seekTo(mStartPosition);

    mTimeVideo = mDuration;
    mRangeSeekBarView.initMaxWidth();
}
```

Now  i want to that with size.....

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the size" ? I've noticed you are using K4LVideoTrimmer which is this library : https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer , right? If so, maybe you could use this library I've made, to make it easier for you to modify and see if it helps: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/VideoTrimmer